# Como hacer únicos los atributos de una clase en java

Tags: java, poo, objeto, booleano

Quiero lograr que al momento de crear un segundo objeto de dicha clase , tenga obligatoriamente en el atributo String nombre único y no que marque error cuando se use

```
CompaniesProductoras co1 = new CompaniesProductoras("Tropicana", "34", "123");
CompaniesProductoras co2 = new CompaniesProductoras("Tropicana", "35", "245");
CompaniesProductoras co3 = new CompaniesProductoras("Tropicana", "36", "678");
```

ahora mismo no consigo que cada nombre sea único esto intente desde la clase CompaniesProductoras

```
private String nombre = "";
private String numeroRFC;
private String telefono;

public CompaniesProductoras(String nombre, String numeroRFC, String telefono ) {

    //Esta seria la validacion de nombre unico
    validarNombreUnico(nombre);
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.numeroRFC = numeroRFC;
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public  boolean validarNombreUnico(String nombre ) {
    if (this.nombre.equals(nombre)) {
        System.out.println("E R R O R \n NO SE PERMITEN NOMBRES IGUALES EN LAS COMPANIES PRODUCTORAS");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

quien pueda ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Usa una variable estática de tipo HashSet que guarde todos las compañías que vayas creando, y cada vez que crees una nueva compañía, verifiques si no se ha creado antes. Por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CompaniesProductoras {
    private static Set<String> nombres = new HashSet<>();
    private String nombre = "";
    private String numeroRFC;
    private String telefono;

    public CompaniesProductoras(String nombre, String numeroRFC, String telefono) {
        this.setNombre( nombre );
        this.numeroRFC = numeroRFC;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        if (nombres.contains( nombre )) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "NO SE PERMITEN NOMBRES IGUALES EN LAS COMPANIES PRODUCTORAS" );
        }
        nombres.add( nombre );
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```